# Sorted and ordered data frame of unique values

Tags: r, data.table, tidyverse

Here is a toy data:

```
df <- tibble::tribble( ~var2, ~var1, ~var3,   ~var4,
                      2L,   "A",   1.2,  "1/6/2018",
                      4L,   "A",  1.34,  "1/3/2018",
                      7L,   "B",  2.43,  "1/7/2018",
                      3L,   "C",     4,  "1/4/2018",
                      7L,   "A",   3.2,  "1/9/2018",
                      3L,   "D",   2.3, "1/10/2018",
                      4L,   "A",  0.34,  "1/9/2018",
                      5L,   "C",   4.2,  "1/7/2018",
                      5L,   "D",   6.5, "1/10/2018") %>% 
      mutate(var4 = mdy(var4))
```

I want to create a dataframe of unique values of every variable in df sorted from largest (at the top) to smallest values (at the bottom) and vice-versa for date variables. Also variables should be ordered (left-to-right) from least unique to most unique values. The desire output should be:

```
 df_of_unique_values <- tibble::tribble(~var1, ~var2,    ~var4,  ~var3,
                                        "D",    7L,  "1/3/2018",   6.5,
                                        "C",    5L,  "1/4/2018",   4.2,
                                        "B",    4L,  "1/6/2018",     4,
                                        "A",    3L,  "1/7/2018",   3.2,
                                         NA,    2L,  "1/9/2018",  2.43,
                                         NA,    NA, "1/10/2018",   2.3,
                                         NA,    NA,          NA,  1.34,
                                         NA,    NA,          NA,   1.2,
                                         NA,    NA,          NA,  0.34) %>% 
  mutate(var4 = mdy(var4))
```

How can I do that preferably using tidyverse?

Comment: You tagged this `data.table` but don't use anything from that package

Comment: I wanted to keep that option open in case other options in R did not provide the desired results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Borrowing from [Combining lists of different lengths into data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42774843/combining-lists-of-different-lengths-into-data-frame):

```
str(lists <- lapply(df, function(a) sort(unique(a), decreasing=!inherits(a,"Date"))))
# List of 4
#  $ var2: int [1:5] 7 5 4 3 2
#  $ var1: chr [1:4] "D" "C" "B" "A"
#  $ var3: num [1:9] 6.5 4.2 4 3.2 2.43 2.3 1.34 1.2 0.34
#  $ var4: Date[1:6], format: "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-06" "2018-01-07" ...
str(lists <- lists[order(lengths(lists))])
# List of 4
#  $ var1: chr [1:4] "D" "C" "B" "A"
#  $ var2: int [1:5] 7 5 4 3 2
#  $ var4: Date[1:6], format: "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-06" "2018-01-07" ...
#  $ var3: num [1:9] 6.5 4.2 4 3.2 2.43 2.3 1.34 1.2 0.34
(maxlen <- max(lengths(lists)))
# [1] 9
str(lists <- lapply(lists, function(l) c(l, rep(NA, maxlen-length(l)))))
# List of 4
#  $ var1: chr [1:9] "D" "C" "B" "A" ...
#  $ var2: int [1:9] 7 5 4 3 2 NA NA NA NA
#  $ var4: Date[1:9], format: "2018-01-03" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-06" "2018-01-07" ...
#  $ var3: num [1:9] 6.5 4.2 4 3.2 2.43 2.3 1.34 1.2 0.34
as.data.frame(lists)
#   var1 var2       var4 var3
# 1    D    7 2018-01-03 6.50
# 2    C    5 2018-01-04 4.20
# 3    B    4 2018-01-06 4.00
# 4    A    3 2018-01-07 3.20
# 5 <NA>    2 2018-01-09 2.43
# 6 <NA>   NA 2018-01-10 2.30
# 7 <NA>   NA       <NA> 1.34
# 8 <NA>   NA       <NA> 1.20
# 9 <NA>   NA       <NA> 0.34
```

Tidyverse equivalent:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

maxlen <- max(lengths(map(df, unique)))
df %>%
  map(~ sort(unique(.), decreasing = !inherits(., "Date"))) %>%
  .[order(lengths(.))] %>%
  map(`length<-`, maxlen) %>%                    # alternative 1
  # map(~ c(., rep(NA, maxlen - length(.)))) %>% # alternative 2
  tbl_df()
```

---

Bottom line, though: I agree with @42- and @thelatemail that this is really not the best format for storage. One interpretation of a `data.frame` is that everything on a row is related. In surveys, for example, each column is a question, each row is a respondent (survey-taker). By reordering differently between the columns, this association is completely discarded. The only rationale I can think of for *not* going with a simpler `list` format (as @42- ended with) is for report presentation, where I assume you'd do something like

```
options(knitr.kable.NA="")
knitr::kable(...)
# |var1 | var2|var4       | var3|
# |:----|----:|:----------|----:|
# |D    |    7|2018-01-03 | 6.50|
# |C    |    5|2018-01-04 | 4.20|
# |B    |    4|2018-01-06 | 4.00|
# |A    |    3|2018-01-07 | 3.20|
# |     |    2|2018-01-09 | 2.43|
# |     |     |2018-01-10 | 2.30|
# |     |     |           | 1.34|
# |     |     |           | 1.20|
# |     |     |           | 0.34|
```

Comment: Just need to sort variables from largest to smallest values for variables and vice-versa for date variables.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Also curious if it can be written using purrr and dplyr?

Comment: You can also take advantage of `length<-` if you want - `lapply(lists, \`length<-\`, maxlen)`

Comment: Yeah, I knew that ... at some point. *sigh*. thanks for reminding me.

Comment: @r2evans - I just realised that my suggestion actually breaks the Date variable. How unfortunate.

Comment: I'm missing it ... seems to work fine for me, I see `<date>` in the tidy version with either `purrr::map` or `lapply`, still sorted correctly.

Comment: Absolutely r3evans, presenting, not analysing, unique values is the objective!

Comment: r2evans, i can’t get my head around the `length<-`, can you please change that to the one you had previously suggested?

Comment: The expression `length(vec) <- newlen` changes the length by truncating or extending/padding with `NA`. That functionality was created with `\`length<-\` <- function(vec, newlen) {...}`, which is a special function in R. Other special functions are meant to be used either infix (`%in%`) or on the left hand side of an assignment (`names(vec) <- c(...)`). Defining the special functions requires the backticks; using "normally" does not, but using programmatically like this requires the backticks again. Make sense?

Comment: Geet: I've re-added the alternative as a comment. Can you see the `edited x hours ago` to the left of my name under the answer? If you click on that, you can see the history of edits, including redactions, changes, additions. (I don't recall if this requires a minimum reputation.)

Comment: It's a handy tool to see (a) what somebody thought was wrong or insufficient, and (b) remind yourself why you thought you saw something but now don't ... I use it frequently. Glad it helped.

Answer (score 3):

I suppose one could use tidyverse by this seems really simple with `order`:

```
df[order(df$var1, df$var2, df$var3, -as.numeric(df$var4)),]
# A tibble: 9 x 4
   var2 var1   var3 var4      
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <date>    
1     2 A      1.2  2018-01-06
2     4 A      0.34 2018-01-09
3     4 A      1.34 2018-01-03
4     7 A      3.2  2018-01-09
5     7 B      2.43 2018-01-07
6     3 C      4    2018-01-04
7     5 C      4.2  2018-01-07
8     3 D      2.3  2018-01-10
9     5 D      6.5  2018-01-10
```

This is the tidyverse equivalent. Needed to find the `?arrange` help page which advises using `desc()` for reverse ordering (the equivalent of using `-` prefix when using `order):

```
df %>% arrange(var1, var2, var3, desc(as.numeric(var4)))
# A tibble: 9 x 4 
   var2 var1   var3 var4      
  <int> <chr> <dbl> <date>    
1     2 A      1.2  2018-01-06
2     4 A      0.34 2018-01-09
3     4 A      1.34 2018-01-03
4     7 A      3.2  2018-01-09
5     7 B      2.43 2018-01-07
6     3 C      4    2018-01-04
7     5 C      4.2  2018-01-07
8     3 D      2.3  2018-01-10
9     5 D      6.5  2018-01-10
```

A list would be the way to return values that are of unequal lengths and unrelated to each other:

```
lapply(df, unique)
$var2
[1] 2 4 7 3 5

$var1
[1] "A" "B" "C" "D"

$var3
[1] 1.20 1.34 2.43 4.00 3.20 2.30 0.34 4.20 6.50

$var4
[1] "2018-01-06" "2018-01-03" "2018-01-07" "2018-01-04" "2018-01-09" "2018-01-10"
```

Comment: I need to only see the unique values of variables as I have millions of rows and sorted like the df_of_unique_values.

Comment: That result should not be either a tibble or dataframe but rather a list.

Comment: The intermediate step could be lists that should be stitched in one tibble somehow as there could be hundreds of variables.

Comment: Lists would not be a problematic  storage structure.

Comment: @Geet - it would be quite contradictory to use the tidyverse coding logic and then use an output format that is close to the least tidy structure possible.

Comment: The objective is to show, not analyse, unique values for say 50 variables. And, between 50 different lists and a data frame, I found data frame to be more convenient to show. It’s for review, especially for variables with limited number of unique values hence ordering and sorting of variables was so important to me.